# OctoberCMS Backend Loging Hash Error

Tags: octobercms

I'm very new to using OctoberCMS, so this one has me stumped.  I've had a test site up and running on my local machine for two days.  No real problems to speak of.  Tonight I went to log in to the backend and I couldn't get in.  I keep getting the following message:

```
A user was found to match all plain text credentials however hashed credential "password" did not match.
```

How can this happen?  I've done absolutely nothing to alter any user, login, backend, or hashing within the CMS.  This is simply a mystery to me.  And more importantly, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error, but may not be the best error message. To resume, the error is the following :
`Your password didn't match with your username`.

An easy way to fix that would be to reset the password with the password recovery tool.

Another way would be to generate a new password, with the exsisting Encryption key in `config/app.php`. Find the encryption key, go to a encryption website (ex. http://aesencryption.net/) then find result of encryption. Then modify your password in users table, in the DB. **Remember, the encryption is 128 bits.**

The easiest way would be to reinstall October with all the plugins and themes, then run `php artisan october:up` to migrate (seed the db).

Hope this help.

Comment: Actually what it means is that my password did match my username in plain text, but that somehow the hashing was altered so that a plain text password that is hashed before comparison to the database no longer matches.  This left me completely unwilling to simply reset the password as I have no idea how or why the hashing was altered so I have no faith that it won't repeat the error.  In the end I just trashed the site and rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

After running

`php artisan october:install`

You will see some info

`The following password has been automatically generated for the "admin" account: ISXM0Vj1fOcEshDGXL7vn4`

OctoberCMS generates and automatic password regardless of whether you input your preferred password.

Copy the 'generated password' (in my case:`ISXM0Vj1fOcEshDGXL7vn4`) and login with that. You can then change the password in the admin My account page. [image: automatic password generated]

[image: backend change password]

Answer (score 0):

> Running `php artisan october:install` will guide you through the
>   process of setting up OctoberCMS for the first time. It will ask for
>   the database configuration, application URL, encryption key and
>   administrator details.

However, if OctoberCMS is already installed, the command will prompt you for new configuration while also showing you the current ones. There, you will be able to get your password.

Here is an example where both my *username* and *password* are **admin**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this [bycrypt hash generator](https://bcrypt-generator.com/) to generate a new password and replace the old one in the `backend_users` table. You will then be able to login again in the backend using the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, New users who installed October with installer package, face this problem.

At new installation, login infos are **admin** - **admin**. Even if you installed/set  with different information.